# Error while publishing a mxd as service uing python

Tags: python, web-service

I have created an Excel file with Lat/lon values. I added this data tas a layer in the ArcMap. And I "used Display XY data" otion available  on right click. I selected the GCS_WCS_1984 co-ordinate system. I then saved it as ArcMap document(.mxd).

I get this error when I am trying to publish my MXD file(created above) as service using python script:

Layer's data source has a different projection [GCS_WGS_1984] than the data frame's projection   (Code 10001)

Any pointers will be helpful.

I fixed it.
For the benefit of others the problem was due to the wrong option which I chose suring creation of shape file. I changed the option to "the data frame" and bingo the error was gone.Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. For the benefit of others the problem was due to the wrong option which I chose suring creation of shape file. I changed the option to "the data frame" and bingo the error was gone.Cheers !